# RewriteRule - Special Characters (Ex:// http://test.com/test_)

Tags: html, apache, url-rewriting

As the title states, how would I change my rewrite rules so it will allow special characters such as _, -, or _ inside of my rules

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]
```

My overall goal is to allow links such as

```
http://mywebsite.com/users/test_
```

Without giving a 404 because it's not allowing the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9:_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9:_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]
```